# Use jquery to display div based on radio button selected

Tags: jquery

Here's the code for a simple page I have that is not working:

```
    <head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$("input[type=radio]").on('click', function(){
    if ($('#radio1').is(':checked')){
        $("#grid_9.omega").slideDown("slow");
    } else { 
        $("#grid_9.omega").slideUp("slow");
    }
});
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio1" id="radio1" />
      Radio 1</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio2" id="radio2" />
      Radio 2</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio3" id="radio3" />
      Radio 3</label>
    <br />
  </p>
</form>
<div id="grid_9" class="omega" style="display:none">show me when Radio 1 is chosen​</div>
</body>
```

My goal is to use jquery to display div "grid_9.omega" when "radio1" is selected, but have that div hidden when "radio1" isn't selected.

Advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nejj/9369U/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("input[type=radio]").on('click', function(){
    if ($('#radio1').is(':checked')){
        $("#grid_9.omega").slideDown("slow");
    } else { 
        $("#grid_9.omega").slideUp("slow");
    }
});
});
</script>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio1" id="radio1" />
      Radio 1</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio2" id="radio2" />
      Radio 2</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio3" id="radio3" />
      Radio 3</label>
    <br />
  </p>
</form>
<div id="grid_9" class="omega" style="display:none">show me when Radio 1 is chosen</div>
```

All I changed from your code was I added the document ready in the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 3):

Simply you can do:

```
$("input[type=radio]").on('click', function(){
    if(this.id == 'radio1')
        $("#grid_9.omega").slideDown("slow");
    else
       $("#grid_9.omega").slideUp("slow");
});
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/9369U/2/)**

If your radio is dynamic i.e. append to DOM after page load then you need delegate event handler like following:

```
$('body').on('click', 'input[type=radio]', function() {
  if(this.id == 'radio1')
      $("#grid_9.omega").slideDown("slow");
  else
     $("#grid_9.omega").slideUp("slow");
});
```

Instead of `input[type=radio]` you can use only `:radio` as selector. i.e

```
$(':radio').on('click', ...)
```

or

```
$('body').on('click', ':radio',..)
```

---

#### Note

In case of delegate event it would be better to use any other static element instead of `body`. Suppose, if your `form1` is Static to DOM i.e belong to DOM at time of page load then instead of

```
$('body').on('click', 'input[type=radio]', function() {..})
```

you should use

```
$('#form1').on('click', 'input[type=radio]', function() {..})
```

---

#### Remainder

Place all of your code within

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // your code
});
```

is short

```
$(function() {
  // your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(function(){
    $(document).on('change','input:radio', function(){
        if ($('#radio1').is(':checked')){
            $("#grid_9.omega").slideDown("slow");
        } else { 
            $("#grid_9.omega").slideUp("slow");
        }
    });
}
//-->
</script>
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fHxRZ/1/)

Comment: also should it be 'input[type="radio"]' - with the double quotes?

Comment: missed a `,`. please try again